# Android page curl by harism , curling the page from left to right

Tags: android, page-curl

I need to edit harism's project about [page curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) to make pages turns from left to right instead of right to left.

From where should I start?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue , can you help me with the same. I want to curl page from left to right but the issue i am facing is regarding the right image at the right index this is not happening

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is same with me, I have modify [Curl Page](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) from harism to fit it. thanks to harism and I hope harism can make official patch.
[Curl Page From Left to Right while view mode set to SHOW_ONE_PAGE:](http://dream-fighter.blogspot.com/2012/10/curl-page-harism-modify-left-to-right.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16772734/1503130 try if you can share any idea in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set the current index to the last position and swipe back to first?

```
mPageProvider= new PageProvider();
mCurlView = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curl);
mCurlView.setPageProvider(mPageProvider);
mCurlView.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(index);
mCurlView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF202830);

mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(mPageProvider.mBitmapIds.length);
```

Comment: thanks hotveryspicy , but you may understand me wrongly , what I mean is that I want to make the pages fliping animation from left to right (imagen yourself read an Aarabic book)

Comment: @hotveryspicy please look at the above thread I got stuck in here, guess you may give me an idea to proceed.

Comment: can any one send me the code for left to right curl page animation...thanks my email is sardarkhan299@gmail.com