# Curl page from left to right android

Tags: android, android-layout, page-curl, android-query

So , I am using page curl by harism , https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl and have successfully implemented it for loading images via web streaming. But can't get it work when I flip back to the previous images or pages as the images are not coming with the right index. i.e. they are not refreshing properly. I can't figure this out.

This is my implementation where I load images to the `PageProvider`

```
private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {


        @Override
        public int getPageCount() {
            return data1.size()-1;
        } 

        private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, final int index) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

            System.out.println("value of current page index "+mCurlView.getCurrentIndex()+" and index is "+index);

            System.out.println("url forward");
            aq.ajax(data1.get(index+1), Bitmap.class,0, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                    if(object!=null)
                           try {
                                System.out.println("url image downloaded "+url);
                                y=object;

                                aq.ajax(data1.get(index).replace(".png", ".mp3"), File.class,0,new AjaxCallback<File>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void callback(String url, File object, AjaxStatus status) {

                                        System.out.println("url sound downloaded "+url);
                                        try {
                                              if(object!=null)
                                               {    
                                                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(object);

                                                if(index>0)
                                                 {  
                                                  mPlayer.stop();
                                                  mPlayer.reset();
                                                 }

                                                prepareMediaPlayer(inputStream.getFD());
                                                inputStream.close();
                                               }
                                            }
                                        catch (Exception e) {}
                                   }
                                });     
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }); 


            d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),y);

            if(y!=null)
            {   
            int margin = 7; 
            int border = 3;
            Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

            int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
            int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                    / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
                imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
                imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                        / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            }

            r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
            r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
            r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
            r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
            c.drawRect(r, p);
            r.left += border;
            r.right -= border;
            r.top += border;
            r.bottom -= border;

            d.setBounds(r);
            d.draw(c);
            }
            //}
            if(y==null)
            return null;

            else
            return b;   
        }

        @Override
        public void updatePage(CurlPage page, final int width, final int height, final int index) {

                Bitmap front = null;

                System.out.println("motion / index value /countIteration / size of map "+motionDirection+"/"+index+"/"+countIteration+"/"+imageFilexxSm.size());

                try {


                     front=loadBitmap(width, height,index);

                    if(front!=null)
                    {
                    page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                    page.setColor(Color.rgb(180, 180, 180), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}}
```

Also I have tried setting the index using `getCurrentIndex` method that is provided inside the CurlView class , but it even doesn't work. Have found that the index gets passed correctly but the bitmaps are not getting refreshed.

More clearly the problem is:

When I move in forward direction i.e. 1st , 2nd , 3rd , 4th , 5th ... the images and sounds works correctly , but when I do the reverse 5th , 4th , 3rd , 2nd , 1st then only 5th to 4th curl is right but 3rd , 2nd and 1st are out of order. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hope this would save someone's time if using an imageloading library
>   with harism page curl.

So, after a lot of research I found that the imageloading library I was using `(aquery)` has got methods i.e. `getCachedImage(String url)` , `getCachedFile(String url)` which doesn't work on the threads and return `null` if the file is not already cached into any storage **(sdcard , cache directory)**.

The piece of code that was actual did it for me is ,

```
private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {


    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return data1.size()-1;
    } 

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, final int index) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

        System.out.println(" Index is : "+index+" Curl state : "+CurlActivity.motionDirection);

        if(index==data1.size())
        {
        lastPage=false; 
        }

        else
        {
        lastPage=true;  
        }   

        if(CurlActivity.motionDirection==11)
             {
                y=aq.getCachedImage(data1.get(index));
                f=aq.getCachedFile(data1.get(index+1).replace(".png", ".mp3"));

                if(f!=null)
                {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

                if(index>0)
                     {  
                        mPlayer.stop();
                        mPlayer.reset();
                     }

                 prepareMediaPlayer(inputStream.getFD());
                 inputStream.close();
               }
            }

            else
            {
                y=aq.getCachedImage(data1.get(index));

                if(jump==0)
                 { 
                  f=aq.getCachedFile(data1.get(index).replace(".png", ".mp3"));
                 }

                else
                 {
                  f=aq.getCachedFile(data1.get(index+1).replace(".png", ".mp3"));
                 }


                if(y!=null&&f!=null)
                {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

                if(index>0)
                     {  
                        mPlayer.stop();
                        mPlayer.reset();
                     }
                 prepareMediaPlayer(inputStream.getFD());
                 inputStream.close();
                }

                else if(y!=null && f == null)
                {
                    duration=1000;
                }

                else
                {   
                aq.progress(R.id.progress).ajax(data1.get(index+1), Bitmap.class,0, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void callback(final String urlimg, final Bitmap object1, AjaxStatus status) {
                    if(object1!=null)
                           try {
                                y=object1;

                                aq.ajax(data1.get(index).replace(".png", ".mp3"), File.class,0,new AjaxCallback<File>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void callback(String url, File object, AjaxStatus status) {

                                        System.out.println("url sound downloaded "+url+status.getCode());
                                        try {
                                              if(object!=null||status.getCode()==404)
                                               {
                                                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(object);

                                                if(index>0)
                                                 {  
                                                  mPlayer.stop();
                                                  mPlayer.reset();
                                                 }

                                                prepareMediaPlayer(inputStream.getFD());
                                                inputStream.close();
                                               }
                                            }
                                        catch (Exception e) {}
                                   }
                                });     
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            });
           }    
        }

        d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),y);

        if(y!=null)
        {   
        int margin = 7; 
        int border = 3;
        Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

        int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
        int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
            imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
            imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                    / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }

        r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
        r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
        r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
        r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
        c.drawRect(r, p);
        r.left += border;
        r.right -= border;
        r.top += border;
        r.bottom -= border;

        d.setBounds(r);
        d.draw(c);
        }

        return b;   
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePage(CurlPage page, final int width, final int height, final int index) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.reset();

            Bitmap front = null;

            try {

                front=loadBitmap(width, height,index);

                if(front!=null)
                {
                page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                page.setColor(Color.rgb(180, 180, 180), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      } 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959530/curlview-get-the-position-of-the-image-clicked Can check this thread!

Answer (score 2):

hm... curlpage by harism has behavior to load image more than one when flipping page, example if you flipping page from 0 to 1 curlpage will load image for page 1 and page 2, and if you flip to page 5 curlpage will load image for page 5 and 6, but if you flipping back to page 4, curlpage will load image for page 4, page 3 and page 2.

`loadImage()` triggered when onTouch `ACTION.MOVE`, so you have to prepared the image before you move/flip the page or your page will be get null, you have to load manually by calling `updatePage()` method in CurlView class.

for `getCurrentIndex()` you can check it  in method `startCurl()` and `updatePage()` in CurlView class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you make it more clear by adding a code example or direction in what do I do step by step , I mean 1st , 2nd , 3rd ...

Comment: Just for your assistance and time I would like to award my bounty to you. Well I got the answer myself. Still thanks a lot.

Comment: the above answer not suitable for question..how ..loading page is use as curl the page from left to right.it doesnot work..can you send me the code for how to curl page from left to right..my email is sardarkhan299@gmail.com