# How to use Harism page curl for right to left languages

Tags: android, page-curl

I want to use Harism project in my application. I want to know how can I change the code for right to left languages.

Harism works in one page and two page mode. I guess if I can show left page in one page mode I can use it in my project.

Can anybody help me how can I change the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android page curl by harism , curling the page from left to right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881244/android-page-curl-by-harism-curling-the-page-from-left-to-right)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is very easy to reach what you want. You should just put 10000 or more to value which returns to `getPageCount()` method in `PageProvider` class. In main Activity class you can set `mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(getPageCount())` value to `CurlView` class index. When you reach your book's end page you can simply set 1 or 0 value by `mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(0)` in your main Activity class.

Comment: Yes you're right. But I mean page curl from left to right not justify text. Because in left to right language we curl from right to left and in right to left language we curl from left to right